# Imaginary part of integral of $\exp(kx - x^2/2 + 2\pi i x)$ vanishes over the real axis.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to show that

$$
\int_0^\infty x^k \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\log(x)^2 / 2} \sin(2\pi \log(x)) = 0
$$
for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I thought, that it would be benificial to lift this integral into the complex plane and showed that the upper is equal to
$$
\text{Im}\left[ \int_\mathbb{R} \exp(ky-y^2/2 + i2\pi y)dy\right] = 0.
$$

However, I don't know how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new variable $x = y - k$:

\begin{align*}\int_\mathbb{R} \exp(ky-y^2/2 + i2\pi y)\,dy &= \int_\mathbb{R} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} (y-k)^2 + \frac{k^2}{2} + i 2\pi y\right)\,dy \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{k^2}{2} + i 2\pi x + i 2\pi k\right)\,dx\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{k^2}{2} + i 2\pi x \right)\,dx
\end{align*}
We can drop the $i2\pi k$ term because $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\exp(z) = \exp(z+2\pi i)$. Switching $x$ with $-x$ replaces the argument of $\exp$ with its complex conjugate, and $e^\overline{z} = \overline{e^z}$, so the imaginary part of the integral over $(-\infty, 0]$ cancels the imaginary part of the integral over $[0, \infty)$, and we are done.